# Rails devise - how to present the login form if user is not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, haml

I am new to RoR...just warning you :)

I made this route in routes.rb:

```
  scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      resources :home
         devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "signup" }, :controllers => {:sessions => "sidebar/sessions"}

      resources :disclosures # Will have new, get, look up a disclosure

      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
          { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "signup" }
          # How do I tell is to also take care of the confirm account screen?
    end
  end
```

And I made this HAML page:

```
-content_for :primary_content do
  .content_container
    %strong{:class => "code", :id => "message"} Hello Alex!

  -content_for :primary_content do
    -if signed_in?
      =render "sidebar/common/primary_navigation"
    -else
      =render "devise/sessions/form"
```

and when the user is not logged in, it gives me this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x147fe1990>:0x147fdab40>
```

and

```
1: = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:id => "login-form"}) do |f| 
2:   %fieldset.field-container
3:     = f.label(t :label_login) 
4:     .input
```

and this stack trace:

```
app/views/devise/sessions/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_devise_sessions__form_html_haml__2025707780_2630401320'
app/views/mobile/home/index.html.haml:26:in `_app_views_mobile_home_index_html_haml__2141491110_2759485880'
app/views/mobile/home/index.html.haml:22:in `_app_views_mobile_home_index_html_haml__2141491110_2759485880'
app/views/mobile/home/index.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_mobile_home_index_html_haml__2141491110_2759485880'
app/controllers/mobile/home_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

So if I understand it right, it doesn't know what to do with the form part of the code. Is that correct? What did I do wrong to cause this problem? How do I fix it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to render the devise form.

So remove this:

```
-else
      =render "devise/sessions/form"
```

You need to add this to the top of the controllers you want to authenticate:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

This will cause devise to redirect to the login form if the user is not authenticated.
If he is already authenticated, your normal views will be rendered.

Comment: thanks, that worked to get the HAML html to render. But if I am not logged in, why doesn't it ask me to log in?

Comment: And is there a way to output to the screen if the user is authenticated so I can see if the system is working correctly?  Thanks again!!

Comment: First you should move `devise_for` in your routes above `resources :home`. If the form is being used on `:create` then add it the `:only => []` section.

Comment: I used this in my application.html.erb to display the logout link: `if user_signed_in?` `current_user.name`.

Comment: Here is my sign out link: `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`